# SAS arrays to fill the last value carry forward across multiple columns

Tags: arrays, loops, sas, sas-macro, locf

[As mentioned in the picture sepstrata0, sepstrata1,sepstrata3 have already the last values slong with YAS,YES,YCS columns. I would like to change  the code such a way that the sepstrata0, sepstrata1,sepstrata3 columns remain unaffected while other columns coming from transposed_gen_mod should have the LVCF.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9BuC.png) I've YAS0 YES0 YCS0 YAS1 YES1 YCS1 YAS3 YES3 YCS3 columns where I have values such as "Atrisk" in all YAS columns, similarly "Events" for YES columns and "Censor" for all YCS columns and total I've about 9547 rows and only 1st rows of each column has the values. I would like to caryy forword the values to all 9657 rows.

Could anyone guide me though how to modify the below written code to achieve the results. I have tried to do it through do over loop but couldn't finish it till end.Let me know if i'm on track and help with a solution to modify the code to achieve the results.

```
data plot_data_fin;
merge plot_datafin transposed_gen_mod;
by row;hw_lcl_lag=lag(hw_lcl);
ARRAY cols {*} YAS: YES: YCS: ;
Do i=1 to dim(cols);
if COLS[i]=" " then COLS[i]=lag(COLS[i]);
end;
run;
```

run;

Comment: @Reeza,Sorry about that.please find the below code.                                                                                                                                                      data plot_data_fin;
merge plot_datafin transposed_gen_mod;
by row;hw_lcl_lag=lag(hw_lcl);
ARRAY cols {*} YAS: YES: YCS: ;
Do i=1 to dim(cols);
 if COLS[i]=" " then COLS[i]=lag(COLS[i]);
 end;
run;

Answer (score 0):

If transposed_gen_mod only has one row with YAS etc. columns, and you want to add those values in to every row on plot_datafin, then you can just merge without a by variable.

```
data plot_data_fin;
   merge plot_data_fin transposed_gen_mod;
run;
```

You will get a warning in the log about merging without a by variable, but the result will be correct.

It is unclear how your data is structured so it is hard to answer the question coherently.

Comment: Hi @Jeremy Miller, thanks for your reply. I've tried out your suggestion. No warnings in the log , neither it  worked. Sorry if the datastructure is uncleared . Its as simple as below.